# MainviewModel windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

This is the class where I'm trying to load the data

PAGE2 XAML

```xaml
   <xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1">

            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="10,2,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Height="154">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,538" Height="150"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>


            </phone:LongListSelector>


        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainViewModel

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Package_Tracker_P.Resources;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Package_Tracker_P.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static List<Car> carlist = new List<Car>();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
            this.Items2 = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
        /// </summary>


        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items2 { get; private set; }


        private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string SampleProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _sampleProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _sampleProperty)
                {
                    _sampleProperty = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sample property that returns a localized string
        /// </summary>
        public string LocalizedSampleProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return AppResources.SampleProperty;
            }
        }

        public bool IsDataLoaded
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
        /// </summary>
        public async void LoadData(Car toyota)
        {
            // Sample data; replace with real data
            carlist.Add(toyota);
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = (Items.Count.ToString()), LineOne = toyota.status, LineTwo = "", LineThree = "" });
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
            //await openfile();
            await IO.WriteToFile();
        }

 public async void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                stuff();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Loading Data");
            }
        }
        public void stuff()
        {
            this.Items2.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = (Items2.Count.ToString()), LineOne = "Auto Detect", LineTwo = "", LineThree = "" });
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is is not loading the data for PAGE2. It is loading it for the main page using items1. While the app is loading it calls LoadData() and that call stuff() which is adding data to items2. It is correctly
binded in the xaml file for PAGE TWO in the textblock. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i think the main problem with this code is that you have not set the datacontext of the page 2
like if you are using MVVM light then

```
DataContext = {Binding MainViewModel,Source="{StaticResource Locator}}"
```